# OCR software with location information

Tags: pdf, ocr

I need to automate OCR of some forms. For this purpose, I am looking for a solution that

- handles PDF files both with text or scanned images,
- extracts chunks of text (groups of nearby words),
- instead of outputting a Word format or similar, returns the list of chunks together with the coordinates of the bounding boxes.

Ideally, the tool should be an SDK that I could link to my application, but a stand-alone application outputting a data file is fine too.